# Timer control in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net application where I have added a timer control with interval of 1000ms. I am facing three types of problems:

1) The page, when viewed in browser, is loading itself every second, with the interval of timer.
I do not want this as the application is going to be quite heavy and if final application keeps re-loading it like this, it will be a total failure.

2) The purpose of the timer is to check the time and date every second, when the right time approaches, it should send an email. This function is not working. I am using below code.

```
If DateTime.Now = DateTime.Parse("01.13.2014 20:34") Then
        Call SendEmail()
        Timer1.Enabled = False
    End If
```

3) I want to set this time using DateTimePicker like control, that we use for Winforms. Is anything like that possible? When hosted on server, where shall the time be taken, as on local server, it is taking from my system.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the default behaviour of the Timer Control; once given an Interval and set Enabled = true, it *will* repost the entire page every (Interval) milliseconds.

What you are doing - waiting until a specific time to send an email - is not really a task that is suited to a web application. You *can* do it but I would advise against it; create a Windows Service to do the job instead.

There other alternatives if this sounds too daunting: -

- a console application (running on the server)
- a winforms application (running on the server)
- a SQL scheduled task and SQL Mail (database server)

The Windows Service approach is the one I'd use though.

If you really want to do this using a web page, you should consider using either: -

- A JavaScript-based timer that calls a web service or HttpHandler, or
- Wrap the content required (if any) in an UpdatePanel, and place the timer inside the UpdatePanel

As I said - I wouldn't do it this way. Good luck.